# Unreal - AI's can't target buildings

Tags: ai, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

After following some of the Unreal tutorials, I was able to create an AI that tracks the player. Now I want it to target specific buildings. I have tried various methods of modifying what was demonstrated in the Unreal videos but all I can get my AI controller to do is either stand in place or walk to the center of the nav mesh. Here is an example of what I have done:

[image]

If anyone can help, how can I get my AI to attack the Armory? Thanks.

Comment: Throw in a print node that shows the value of Movement Result

Comment: I have. It says Aborted.

Comment: Does the result change if you set the building's mesh CanEverAffectNavigation value to false?

Comment: Just tried it. It now gets one success then goes back to Aborted.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. Since a building is so large it messes with the acceptance radius making the AI think it has reached its location so it just stays still. I instead made an empty class called Waypoint that I planted around the outside of the building and had the AI move to that location instead. It works just fine now.